# ngModelChange does not update the input's value

Tags: angular

I have a form which uses `*ngFor` to loop over an array to create an input field for each item.

This array starts with 1 item, but when a number is entered into one of the input fields, more items are added to the array based on this number.

I am using `(ngModelChange)` to push the new items to the array when the number is entered.

```
  <form #testForm="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
    <div *ngFor="let test of tests">
      <label for="testProp">Test Property</label>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="test.testProp" (ngModelChange)="inputChange($event)" name="testProp"/>
      <b>Value: {{test.testProp}}</b>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**inputChange function**

```
inputChange(number: any, index: any) {

  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    this.tests.push({});
  }

}
```

**Current behavior**

When binding the item's value it is present, but for some reason the input's value is blank.

**Expected behavior**

The input's value not to be blank.

**Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions**

http://plnkr.co/edit/5P0nt68FSFH2UuEpJRnh?p=preview

- **Angular version:** 2.4.5
- **Browser:** all
- **Language:** TypeScript 2.0.2

Comment: I created an issue at the angular repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14251

Comment: try to remove the bracket  [ngModel]="test.testProp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the same `name` attribute for each input. Adding the index to the name like `name="testProp-{{i}}"`